# Overriding methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, overriding, implements

In other OO languages like Java we can override a function, possible using keywords/annotations like `implements`, `@override` etc.

Is there a way to do so in PHP? I mean, for example:

```
class myClass {
    public static function reImplmentThis() { //this method should be overriden by user
    }
}
```

I want user to implement their own `myClass::reImplementThis()` method.

How can I do that in PHP? If it is possible, can I make it optional?

I mean, if the user is not implementing the method, can I specify a default method or can I identify that the method is not defined (can I do this using `method_exists`)?

Comment: That's exactly what inheritance is for. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: In general, I'd make that non-static, and then the user can just extend myClass - choosing whether or not to redefine `reImplmentThis()`. You don't need to test for the existence of a user's implemention if your default implementation is acceptable.

Comment: You could use and abstract class to extend (as halfer says) and an interface class ( http://www.killerphp.com/articles/php-interfaces/ ) to make sure that the final class has, at least, the functions that you specify. I'm only just learning about these (interfaces) I may be wrong, but from what I've read that seem to be the reason to have them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
abstract class Test
{
    abstract protected function test();

    protected function anotherTest() {

    }
}

class TestTest extends Test
{
    protected function test() {

    }
}

$test = new TestTest();
?>
```

This way the class TestTest must override the function test.

Comment: In the OP's case, `reImplementThis()` would be declared non-abstract, since the default implementation is okay. But yes, +1.

Comment: @Dillen this is not the answer to the question that the user asked, this is just a variant on how it should be done but does not satisfy what the user is asking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You have the option to override a method by extending the class and defining a method with the same name, function signature and access specifier (either public or protected) it had in the base class. The method should not be declared abstract in the base class or you will be required to implement it in the derived class. In you example it would look something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public static function reImplmentThis() { //this method should be overriden by user
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass extends MyClass {
    public static function reImplmentThis() { //the method you want to call
    }
}
```

If the user does not overrides it, MyDerivedClass will still have a reImplmentThis() method, the one inherited from MyClass.

That said, you need to be very careful when invoking extended static methods from your derived class to stay out of trouble. I encourage you to refactor your code to extend instance methods unless you have a very specific need to extend static classes. And if you decide there is no better way than extending static classes please be sure to understand [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) pretty well.

Yes, its possible to check if the method is implemented or not and get a whole lot more of information about a class using [PHP Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

Answer (score 0):

This touches on several OOP subjects.

First, simply overriding an method declared in a parent class is as simple as re-declaring the method in an inheriting class.

E.g:

```php
class Person {

    public function greet(string $whom) {
        echo "hello $whom!";
    }

}

class Tommy extends Person {
    public function greet(string $whom = "everyone") {
        echo "Howdy $whom! How are you?";
    }
}

$a = new Tommy();
$a->greet('World');

// outputs:
// Howdy World! How are you?
```

If on the overriding method you wan to reuse the logic of the overriden one, it's just a matter of calling the parent's method from the extending class::

```
class Tommy
{
    public function greet(string $whom)
    {
        // now with more emphasis!!!
        echo parent::greet(strtoupper($whom)) . "!!!!";
    }
}
```

Now `Tommy::greet()` calls `Person::greet()`, but modifies the result before returning it.

One thing to note is that overriding methods have to be compatible with the overriden one: the method visibility can't be more restrictive than the original one (it's OK to increase visibility), and the number and type of **required** arguments can't conflict with the original delcaration.

This works, because the type of the arguments does not clash with the original, and we have *less* required arguments than on the parent:

```php
class Leo extends Person {
    public function greet(string $whom = "gorgeous", string $greet = "Whatsup" ) {
        echo "$greet $whom. How are you?";
    }
}
```

But this doesn't, since there are additional required arguments. This would make impossible to switch the original class for this one transparently, and thus would  throw a `Warning`:

```php
class BadBob extends Person {
    public function greet(string $whom, string $greet ) {
        echo "$greet $whom. How are you?";
    }
}
```

Additionally, you mention in your question that *"this method should be overriden by the user"*. If you require client classes to actually implement the method, you have a couple of options:

**Abstract classes & methods**

These are methods where the implementation is left empty, and that extending classes **have** to implement to be valid. In we changed our original class `Person` to:

```php
abstract class Person {

    public function greet(string $whom) {
        echo "hello $whom!";
    }

    public abstract function hide();

}
```

- Since now the class contains an abstract method, it needs to be declared as an abstract class as well.
- Now it is not possible to instantiate `Person` directly, you can only extend it in other classes.
- Now all our existing `Person` extending classes would be wrong, and trying to execute the previous code would throw a fatal error.

An example of a valid class extending `Person` now would be:

```php
class Archie extends Person {

    public function hide() {
        echo "Hides behind a bush";
    }
}
```

Any class that extends `Person` **must** declare a public `hide()` method.

**Interfaces**

Finally, you mention interfaces. Interfaces are contracts that implementing classes have to fulfill. They declare a group of public methods **without an implementation body**.

E.g.:

```php
interface Policeman {
    public function arrest(Person $person) : bool;
        
    public function help($what): bool;
}
```

Now we could have class that extended `Person` and implemented `Policeman`:

```php
class Jane extends Person implements Policeman {
    
    public function hide() {
        echo "Jane hides in her patrol-car";
    }
    
    public function arrest(Person $person): bool{
        // implement arrest method
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public function shoot($what): bool {
        // implements shoot() method
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

Importantly, while it's possible to extend only **one** class (there is no multiple inheritance in PHP), it is possible to implement multiple interfaces, and the requirements for each of those have to be fulfilled for the class to be valid.